# Plotting with 2 colors per group

Tags: r, plot, graph, grouping

I have a `data` as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(ymdhms=c(20230301000000,20230301000010,20230301000020,20230301000030,20230301000040,
                          20230301000050,20230301000100,20230301000110),
                 switch=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),
                 power=c(20,21,22,23,20,19,29,28))
```

`ymdhms` means year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. For example, 20230301000000` means 00:00:00 , March 1st, 2023.

`ymdhms` has the values of 10 seconds time intervals. For the `switch` column, `1` means that switch is on and `0` means that switch is off.
What I want to do is plot `power`with respect to `ymdhms`.
So y-axis should be `power` and x-axis should be time.I want x-axis to be represented as the time order and only indicate how many seconds have passed. I also want to visually differentiate whether the `switch` is on or off. If the `switch` is off, I want to color the area as red. If the `switch` is on, I want to color the area as green.

Can you suggest a nice way to visualize what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can try to plot one simple line plot.

First, load the packages needed

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
```

Then make a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(ymdhms=c(20230301000000,20230301000010,20230301000020,20230301000030,20230301000040,20230301000050,20230301000100,20230301000110),switch=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0), power=c(20,21,22,23,20,19,29,28))
```

Next, convert the date-time data into POSIXct format

```
# ymdhms to POSIXct
data$timestamp <- ymd_hms(data$ymdhms)
```

Next, create a status 'Switch'. This will help in coloring the data in plot

```
# status variable 
data$switchStatus <- ifelse(data$switch == 1, "on", "off")
```

Finally, make plot from the data

```
# plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = timestamp, y = power, color = switchStatus)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = lag(timestamp, default = first(timestamp)),
                xmax = timestamp, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = switchStatus), alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  xlab("Time (seconds)") + ylab("Power") +
  theme_classic()
```

This will produce something like below:

[image]

If you want, you could also plot variants such as `step chart` etc.

Let me know if this helped.

Step Chart:

```
# step chart
ggplot(data, aes(x = timestamp, y = power, group = 1)) +
  geom_step(aes(color = factor(switch)), direction = "hv") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Power", color = "Switch")
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! I have one more question. Is there a way to color the whole area red and green? For example, for the switch on, color green vertical line, otherwise color the whole rectangle areas red.

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert data into appropriate format, then `plot` by using `switch` to differentiate colors.

```
data$dt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(formatC(data$ymdhms, format='f'), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))

plot(power ~ dt, data, col=switch + 1, pch=15)
legend('topleft', pch=15, col=1:2, leg=c('off', 'on'))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(ymdhms = c(2.0230301e+13, 20230301000010, 20230301000020, 
20230301000030, 20230301000040, 20230301000050, 20230301000100, 
20230301000110), switch = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), power = c(20, 
21, 22, 23, 20, 19, 29, 28)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot2` solution needs a coercion of `ymdhms` to datetime and of `switch` to factor. This is done in a `dplyr` pipe.

```r
data<-data.frame(ymdhms=c(20230301000000,20230301000010,20230301000020,20230301000030,20230301000040,
                          20230301000050,20230301000100,20230301000110),
                 switch=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),
                 power=c(20,21,22,23,20,19,29,28))

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})

data %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(strptime(formatC(data$ymdhms, format='f'), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')),
         switch = factor(switch, labels = c("off", "on"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, power, color = switch)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`off` = "black", `on` = "red")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Or a line and points plot.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(strptime(formatC(data$ymdhms, format='f'), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')),
         switch = factor(switch, labels = c("off", "on"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, power, color = switch)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`off` = "black", `on` = "red")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>